# How to promote a collaborator to have owner rights

Tags: github, rights, owner

How can I promote a collaborator in a github-Projekt to get admin/owner rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the step-by-step instructions for this:

1. Go to your repository on GitHub
2. Go to the "Settings" tab
3. Go to "Collaborators and teams"
4. Click on the button which is currently labled "write"
5. Select "Admin"

Answer (score 4):

For user account repositories, there are only [two roles left](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/): Owner and Collaborator. Unless you transfer ownership, you can not promote someone to get admin rights.

If you have an [organization](https://help.github.com/articles/about-organizations/) (for public repos only, its free), you will be able to grant access at a finer level.